# How to unpivot the table based on the multiple columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala and Spark to *unpivot* a table which looks like as below:

```
+---+----------+--------+-------+------+-----+
| ID|   Date   |  Type1 | Type2 | 0:30 | 1:00|
+---+----------+--------+-------+------+-----+
|  G| 12/3/2018|  Import|Voltage| 3.5  | 6.8 |
|  H| 13/3/2018|  Import|Voltage| 7.5  | 9.8 |
|  H| 13/3/2018|  Export|   Watt| 4.5  | 8.9 |
|  H| 13/3/2018|  Export|Voltage| 5.6  | 9.1 |
+---+----------+--------+-------+------+-----+
```

I want to transpose it as follow:

```
| ID|Date     | Time|Import-Voltage |Export-Votage|Import-Watt|Export-Watt|

|  G|12/3/2018|0:30 |3.5            |0            |0          |0          |
|  G|12/3/2018|1:00 |6.8            |0            |0          |0          |
|  H|13/3/2018|0:30 |7.5            |5.6          |0          |4.5        |
|  H|13/3/2018|1:00 |9.8            |9.1          |0          |8.9        |
```

And `Time` and `Date` columns should be also merged like

```
12/3/2018 0:30
```

Comment: Interested to see who can do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a straight forward task, but one approach would be to:

1. group `time` and corresponding `value` into a "map" of `time-value` pairs
2. flatten it out into a column of `time-value` pairs
3. perform `groupBy-pivot-agg` transformation using `time` as part of the groupBy key and `types` as the pivot column to aggregate the time-corresponding `value`

Sample code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("G", "12/3/2018", "Import", "Voltage", 3.5, 6.8),
  ("H", "13/3/2018", "Import", "Voltage", 7.5, 9.8),
  ("H", "13/3/2018", "Export", "Watt", 4.5, 8.9),
  ("H", "13/3/2018", "Export", "Voltage", 5.6, 9.1)
).toDF("ID", "Date", "Type1", "Type2", "0:30", "1:00")

df.
  withColumn("TimeValMap", array(
    struct(lit("0:30").as("_1"), $"0:30".as("_2")),
    struct(lit("1:00").as("_1"), $"1:00".as("_2"))
  )).
  withColumn("TimeVal", explode($"TimeValMap")).
  withColumn("Time", $"TimeVal._1").
  withColumn("Types", concat_ws("-", array($"Type1", $"Type2"))).
  groupBy("ID", "Date", "Time").pivot("Types").agg(first($"TimeVal._2")).
  orderBy("ID", "Date", "Time").
  na.fill(0.0).
  show
// +---+---------+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
// | ID|     Date|Time|Export-Voltage|Export-Watt|Import-Voltage|
// +---+---------+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
// |  G|12/3/2018|0:30|           0.0|        0.0|           3.5|
// |  G|12/3/2018|1:00|           0.0|        0.0|           6.8|
// |  H|13/3/2018|0:30|           5.6|        4.5|           7.5|
// |  H|13/3/2018|1:00|           9.1|        8.9|           9.8|
// +---+---------+----+--------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Impressive Leo. Why the use of lit? So, would stack not be an option? I thought indeed the title unpivot may not be quite correct. @Leo C

Comment: @thebluephantom, `lit("0:30")`, for example, is for capturing the literal time label "0:30" which (besides serving as a "key") will be in column `Time`.  I agree `unpivot` may not best describe the requirement, more like a custom `transpose`.

Comment: How can I see the full value of TimeValMap?

Comment: In fact cannot see how withColumn("TimeValMap", array(
    struct(lit("0:30").as("_1"), $"0:30".as("_2")),
    struct(lit("1:00").as("_1"), $"1:00".as("_2"))
  )).   actually works, interesting

Comment: To view the value, simply execute thru the code line that completes the first `withColumn()`.  i.e. `df.withColumn("TimeValMap", ...).show(false)`.  For each of the two time labels, method `struct` creates a `time-value` tuple, and method `array` groups the two tuples in an array-type column.  It's for pairing up the time label and its corresponding value so that the association information is not lost after the following transformations including the `groupBy-pivot`.

Comment: got it, top answer sir

Comment: Thanks Leo, that seems to be a very good answer. Just one question, I am going to transpose, 100 million rows with this approach, do you think this approach is efficient for this volume of data? is there any trick to tune it?

Comment: Can't think of any tuning of significant value at the moment.  I've never had to transpose data in high volume, but would like to caution that transposition at volume is by-nature expensive in Spark (and many other general-purpose distributed data processing systems).